# Operation not permitted even though full disk access is granted

Tags: macos, terminal

So I want to move a few files from one folder to another through terminal, here is my code:

```
sudo mv "Meaning and the English Verb by Geoffrey N. Leech (z-lib.org).epub" 
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro English&IELTS&TOEFL % sudo mv "Meaning and the English Verb 
by Geoffrey N. Leech (z-lib.org).epub" /Users/Yichen/Desktop/学. 
习/linguistics\&English/
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
mv: rename Meaning and the English Verb by Geoffrey N. Leech (z-lib.org).epub to 
/Users/Yichen/Desktop/学习/linguistics&English/Meaning and the English Verb by 
Geoffrey N. Leech (z-lib.org).epub: Operation not permitted
```

I searched online and [this website](https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/) suggestes that I grant full disk access to terminal, except that I have done that already.
[image]
Would someone help me out here? What did I do wrong?
Specs: Macbook Pro mid2014 BigSur

Comment: It's not telling you you can't move it, it's telling you you can't rename it. Can you start over with a minimum reproducible example so it's easier to follow what you're doing?

Comment: Just a hunch, but I have the feeling that this might have something to do with the Chinese characters in the file path. Terminals are sometimes a bit picky when it comes to special characters. Have you tried doing the same thing in a path with only ASCII characters?

Comment: @DLCom - that was part of the reason I asked for a minimum reproducible example. I think there's also some formatting issue in the posted code - which would be solved  by pasting, selecting, then hitting Ctrl/K [It looks like it was manually formatted before, not aiding the confusion].

Comment: @Tetsujin You are completely right, of course.